# With Hibernate,how can we retrieve entity by primary key, against first level cache without hitting Database if not found ?

Tags: hibernate, caching, optimization

I have a use case doing pagination. Of course, when the user move around, it will hit the same page again. I already have the set of primary keys for the page.

Also, similar search will hit some of the entity already loaded in the first level and second level cache.

When I do a query for batch of primary key, Hibernate is not clever enough to avoid calling the database if it has a cache hit. So I want to fix this by using low level API first for the primary and secondary level cache.

So, for example, if I want to load the following primary keys: 1, 2, 3

I just want to call the database with 1 and 3, if 2 is already in first level cache.

So I'm looking for an API like session.peek(MyEntity.class, 2) where the peek function will return null if not found or will return the entity if found in first or second level cache.

I'm ok to create this function from even lower level APIs if they exist.

Answer (score 1):

Actually that's already implemented in Hibernate and it's called **query cache**. Here is how it works:

1. Every time you access first page of your list, Hibernate puts all entities from the first page in second level cache (ID -> entity)
2. Moreover Hibernate will put raw IDs in so called *query cache*. A key in this cache is the query + query parameters (which page and how many items).
3. Next time user accesses the same page, Hibernate first checks query cache. If it hits the cache (the same query was already executed some time ago with the same parameters), it returns the IDs of records that were returned that time.
4. Then it uses second level cache to fetch these records instead of hitting the database. Of course if some record is not in L2, Hibernate automatically fetches it without you noticing.

Sound exactly what you want to achieve. Unforunately tuning and effectively using query cache is very hard and it's easy to misconfigure it, worsening the overall system performance.

Also query cache is not enabled by default. Even when it is, you must explicitly define which queries you want to cache.

Comment: Query cache is not answering the question. It's an answer for a limited set of use cases. The following link does answer the questions: https://thoughts-on-java.org/fetch-multiple-entities-id-hibernate/